# Is there a GUID alternative for distributed key generation?

Tags: c#, .net, database, guid, crc

My situation is :

1. I have a number of client applications, which is using local DB (MS SQL, MS Access - sorry, this is Enterprise system, I have to support legacy...)
2. I don't know anything of trend among clients - now it's ~10 but it may
   be ~100 in a year.
3. Data from those tables comes to my central server and is put into one common table
4. Sometimes existing (client) data is changed - I have to perform update/delete operations
5. I don't want use GUID's (.NET type `System.Guid`) - It's hard to simply implement and support on MS Access. Besides, it's [not good for performance](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
6. I need a fast search on that common table, so it would be nice to use `int` or `long int` as a PK

So, I want:

1. Something unique to avoid collisions (it will be used as a PK)
2. It should hopefully be `int` or `long int`
3. Must be assignable client-side before being inserted

My current solution is to take the CRC from a concatenation of:

- ProcessodID
- Bios date
- User name (strings, hardware\user related data)
- DateTime.Now (UNC)

Currently it works for me, but maybe there is a better approach to achieve my goals?
Any comments, suggestions, examples, or experience of your own?

UPDATE : synchronization between client and server is periodic action, so it can occurs 2-3 times per day (it's config variable)

Comment: Could you generate a GUID and then take the first or last x bits to make an int/long?

Comment: Yes, it's good - but only for one client application. I have a few with different locations\workstations, so this is not my case..

Comment: @TimS. For a DB primary key you need no collisions, not just a low % of collisions.  I agree that identity makes the most sense for a PK.

Comment: @Tim S. - How would that serve as a unique id?

Comment: If the table is so large that you have a performance problem with GUID's than you must certainly will have a problem with collisions if you are using a 64 bit int and a CRC checksum alg. for the pk. Have you determined that GUID's really is a performance problem or are you only guessing.

Comment: @nos - they have to be assigned on the client side

Comment: Andriy, have you considered sequential GUID's (as in NEWSEQUENTIALID())? The linked article also mentions that as a good clustering key option. I have had success with them in terms of insert/update/select performance.

Comment: Are these existing apps that you're aggregating, or something you're developing now? If you're developing (or updating), as is implied by changing the DB structure, there's absolutely no reason to use MS Access DBs when you can be using embedded SQLite/SQLCE/etc.

Comment: If data from multiple tables comes to one central table  and you need to address changes to these records then my suggestion is to use two columns as PK of you central table. One column could be the Identity field from clients (not unique) and one column could be a client code (not unique) assigned from you to your client apps. The aggregate from ID and client code will be your PK

Comment: @Alan - I don't think that would work since you have multiple clients creating the IDs.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan - Unfortunatly, I have support Access, no way out. I may change DB structure, I may start develop new client (actually I'm doing it and use MS SQL Express), but..

Comment: @Steve - I was just going to post that as an answer but decided not to since I don't know if data from one client is then moved out to the other clients. It would complicate doing the ClientId+ClientIdentity idea in that case.

Comment: @hatchet: Granted, it increases the probability of collisions, but I still doubt that'd realistically become a problem with only 10-100 clients.

Comment: @hatchet right but I think improbable, and for a such a special case I will prefer to work outside of the programming environment, but waiting a clarification from Andry

Comment: What about Guid.ToString()?  It might not be great for search performance, but it might be good enough.

Comment: Do the clients and common server table to have the same key at all times? Or is there enough uniqueness amoung your client side columns? Do you need to publish update/changes from one client to another?

I ask, because the simpliest solution, under what you have currently described, seems to be to let the server assign the "master key value" when it gets new data, and just use the normal publish of "new" data to the clients.

Updating rows going out will already have a key. Incoming rows that are in the master will already have a value.

The only trick is on the source client...

Comment: The original source client may need to spot it already has that row (being the source), and therefore can just update its source row with the published "master db key". Otherwise, it can simply discard its processed row for the incoming master update.

If the master key is being generated purely at collection/processing time by the master common table, you can just use an autoincrementing PK.

Again, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: @StarPilot - clients don't know anything about each other, only about server. Server looks as some kind of "brain", mediator (GoF patterns). And there is also one moment I have to describe (maybe update question) - synchronization is periodic action, so it can occurs 2-3 times per day (it's config variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data from multiple tables comes to one central table and you need to address changes to these records then my suggestion is to use two columns as PK of you central table. One column could be the Identity field from clients (not unique) and one column could be a client code (not unique) assigned by you to your client apps. The aggregate from ID and client code will be your PK

This solution has the advantage to not require any changes on the client side apps (perhaps some identity code to send to your central server where you could use for some security measure)
Of course, if the customer base grows (hopefully) you need to keep a centralized table of code assigned to each client. The search on the central table should not be a problem because you are using two numbers (or short string for the identity code).

Comment: +1 This a good solution *as long as* the client id is also stored with every cross referenced key. That is, you can never refer to a record by just its client-side key, or else that key will become useless when synced to the central DB.

Comment: @DanRasmussen Sorry, but I don't get it, the client is unaware of the PK used on the central table. It sends its update with its identity code and its primarykey ID, it is the app that manages the central table that should find the correct record and update (or create)

Comment: Actually, you could just assume that every relational key only relates to other rows from the same client, and you would be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just add a PK column that is a number, and (depending on the DB you are using) setup a sequence or identity to handle it.

You could also create an index over the multiple columns your currently have to help speed up your searching.

Comment: This does not allow keys to be assigned client-side. (A requirement OP clarified in the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [key table](http://www.mindscapehq.com/documentation/lightspeed/Controlling-the-Database-Mapping/Identity-Generation#_Toc297195003).

Basically, the key table is just a table with one record: the next available integer key. When your program needs to generate a key, it increments the key in the key table. It has now reserved the previously available key. It can assign that key to whatever it likes and will be assured that it will not conflict with any other key pulled in the same manner. This is how the [LightSpeed ORM](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) works by default. Its benefit over using the built-in identity column is that you can assign item ids before inserting them to the database, and therefor can define item relationships before inserting all items at once.

If you're worried about conflicts, you can lock/unlock the key table before reading and incrementing the next available key. If you know you need to insert more than one item at a time, you can increment the key by that much instead of by one multiple times. If you are guessing that sometime in the future of your application you will need a certain number of keys, you can reserve a block of sequential keys, and keep track of them internally. This may possibly waste keys if you don't assign them all, but prevents excessive calls to the database.

Comment: This assumes that the clients are connected. They may not be when they create a row.

Comment: Actually, this may be a solution, but not better than my current. It your case insert will be dramatically slow (I'm using WCF to connect clients applications and server side, so it depends on)

Comment: @hatchet The clients don't need to be always connected. They can reserve a block of keys to pull from, then they can create that many rows before needing to connect again. Even if they can't connect, they can use temporary ids until they can reserve the necessary ids from the table.

Comment: @Andriy.Zakharko Why will insert be dramatically slow? You can reserve a large block of keys to use, so you don't need any extra database calls when inserting values. It's also guaranteed not to conflict - something your current method can't actually do.

Comment: While workable this will end in a nightmare from a concurrency handling point of view.

Comment: @Steve If the clients are generating 10-100 records in a year (I could have terribly misunderstood point 2) one should worry much more about uniqueness over concurrency.

Comment: @DanRasmussen I think that ~10 ~100 numbers are the clients not the records

Comment: @Dan Rasmussen - according your approach, client side would not be able to insert local record without asking server about next PK value, would it? If I got you right, next available value will be provided by server? In this case client will be fail in case some temporary connection issue

Comment: @Andriy.Zakharko could you explain if the solution, proposed  in the question comments from me and hatchet, is workable?

Comment: @Andriy.Zakharko Your client, when it's connected to the database, could reserve `N` sequential key values. It can then disconnect from the database and use these keys, safe in the knowledge that they will not be used by any other client. If you need to generate record `N+1`, you will need to reconnect and reserve more keys. You can adjust your `N`, however, so that this occurs infrequently. Using an `N` of 1 would be, as you suggest, very inefficient.

Comment: @Steve - yes, your solution looks really the best, so please add it as an answer

Comment: @Dan Rasmussen - yes, it's possible, but let face it - this is a complicated solution : I have to implement additional logic, keep track it.. it puts more places in the code (server and client) to make a bottle neck. Anyway, thanks for propose

Answer (score 1):

Just use a int64 key, on the client side use negatively incrementing numbers away from 0 (starting at -1) and then on the server side after the sync use positive incrementing numbers, when you sync data from the client to the server you then just return the new positive server side numbers. I trust updating the key on a record is simple enough, if not then just delete the old and insert a new one with the values.

This is a really simple way to have client side unique keys and updateble data without really needing to worry about the problems caused by your solution which at very best will just be randomly clashing depending how large your crc check is.

If you're dead set against using a GUID ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) for System.Guid.NewGuid() indicates that  MAC address as part of the value and make them highly unique) then you're answer is either a composite key (and NOT one based on a crc of a composite key!); Please do not fall into the mistake of thinking that your CRC solution is less likely for a collision than a GUID unless you have more entropy than a 128 bit GUID, you're only making more work for yourself.

As I point out, there's the whole negative spectrum of int64 space that you could use to identify unsynchronised and hence temporary unique ID numbers. You then even get the added potential benefits of a clustered index when writing to the central server.

So suppose your client side data keys look like this:

```
-5, -4, 76, 78, 79
```

that means -4 and -5 need to be inserted into the central location and then get their ids updated to the new value (likely `80` and `81` in this example).

If you want further reading on the uniqueness on GUIDs and the likelihood of a collision I suggest you read Eric Lippert's [recent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/24/guid-guide-part-one.aspx) blog [posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx) on the [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx). And as for the Access side, you can just .ToString() and convert them over to a text key. But since I have provided a solution that would work for int / int64 space this would not be required.

Comment: Updating all those keys is going to be a mess... especially if other rows are using them to as relational keys.

Comment: @DanRasmussen If you're using SQL Server you just use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and it will do all the work for you. If you're using a ORM many support cascading to all defined relational keys. If neither of those then it's still not going to be that complex to update the foreign key relations manually. In any case, I think you significantly overestimate how much work it would be to update all the keys.

Comment: The key benefit of this approach is for when you have more than one table you want to sync, if you have 10 tables, each with a key you want to sync then SQL will cascade the new IDs for you and you just do one update per key and forget about it.